# Javascript conflict: Div scrolling speed control & image shrink on scroll together

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been wrestling with this problem for a while without success, so I'm hoping someone with greater knowledge can offer a solution.

By using a script to independently control the scroll speeds of specific divs, I've managed to create an effect along the lines of parallax scrolling:
https://neilwhitedesign.co.uk/pt_testing_area/index(scrolling).html

However, what I would also like to add, is a second script to reduce the size of the logo when the page is scrolls:
https://neilwhitedesign.co.uk/pt_testing_area/index(headershrink).html

Independently, these scripts are working exactly as I want them, but when I try to combine the two, there is a conflict and only the scrolling effect works.

Looking at similar questions posted previously, one solution was to add a further script between the two, to call a **noConflict**.
However, while adding this now makes the shrinking image effect work, it does so at the expense of the scrolling effect.

- Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?
- Is there a simple solution to get around the conflict?

Please find my html and css below:

**HTML**

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  growShrinkLogo()
};

var Logo = document.getElementById("Logo");
var endOfDocumentTop = 90;
var size = 0;

function growShrinkLogo() {
  var scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 90;

  if (size == 0 && scroll > endOfDocumentTop) {
    Logo.className = 'smallLogo';
    size = 1;
  } else if (size == 1 && scroll <= endOfDocumentTop) {
    Logo.className = 'largeLogo';
    size = 0;
  }
}

$.fn.moveIt = function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var instances = [];

  $(this).each(function() {
    instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
  });

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    instances.forEach(function(inst) {
      inst.update(scrollTop);
    });
  }
}

var moveItItem = function(el) {
  this.el = $(el);
  this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};

moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop) {
  var pos = scrollTop / this.speed;
  this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + +pos + 'px)');
};

$(function() {
  $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */


/* 2. Clearfix*/

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1
}


/* 3. Images*/

a img {
  border: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* 4. Structure*/

body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 1.9;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.parallax_container {
  width: 100%;
}

.parallax {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.tagline {
  color: white;
  font-size: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.2;
  z-index: 97;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  height: 900px;
  z-index: 98;
}


/* 5. Logo*/

.logo_container {
  width: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
}

#Logo {
  -webkit-transition: width .5s ease;
  -o-transition: width .5s ease;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}

.largeLogo {
  width: 350px;
}

.smallLogo {
  width: 250px;
}


/* 6. Footer */

footer {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://neilwhitedesign.co.uk/pt_testing_area/css.css" />

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo_container"><img src="https://neilwhitedesign.co.uk/pt_testing_area/logo.png" class="largeLogo" id='Logo'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax_container">
    <div class="tagline" data-scroll-speed="3">This is the tagline</div>
    <div class="parallax" data-scroll-speed="2"><img src="https://neilwhitedesign.co.uk/pt_testing_area/landscape.jpg" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="content" data-scroll-speed="100">Content Area</div>
  <footer>&copy; 2021
    <script src="https://neilwhitedesign.co.uk/pt_testing_area/js/copyright.js"></script> &nbsp;|&nbsp; All rights reserved.</footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Neil White

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should *never* use `on*` handlers (unless you're creating a brand new element from in-memory)  use `.addEventListener()` instead or the jQuery method `.on()` - that way handlers are attached to an element, not overwritten.
- Place `<script>` tags (all of them) right before the closing `</body>` tag
- Use `classList.toggle` or jQuery's `.toggleClass()`
- You don't need two classes for *big* and `small` logo - only one.
- jQuery plugins should use `return` to allow for methods chainability

Here's a remake of the plugin and your scripts:

```js
// moveIt jQuery plugin
$.fn.moveIt = function() {
  const $window = $(window);
  const instances = [];
  const updateItems = () => {
    const scrTop = $window.scrollTop();
    instances.forEach((inst) => inst.update(scrTop));
  };
  $window.on("scroll", updateItems); // Do on scroll
  updateItems(); // and on page load
  // Use "return" to allow $ methods chainability
  return this.each(function(i, el) {
    instances.push(new moveItItem(el));
  });
}
function moveItItem(el) {
  this.el = $(el);
  this.speed = parseInt(this.el.data("scroll-speed"));
};
moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrTop) {
  this.el.css({transform: `translateY(${scrTop / this.speed}px)`});
};

// App
const $window = $(window);
const $logo = $("#Logo");
const docTop = 90;

function growShrinkLogo() {
  $logo.toggleClass("small", $window.scrollTop() > docTop);
}
$window.on("scroll", growShrinkLogo); // Do on scroll
growShrinkLogo(); // and on page load

// moveIt plugin init:
$('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 1.9;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.parallax_container {
  width: 100%;
}

.parallax {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.tagline {
  color: white;
  font-size: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.2;
  z-index: 97;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  height: 900px;
  z-index: 98;
}

.logo_container {
  width: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
}

#Logo {
  -webkit-transition: width .5s ease;
  -o-transition: width .5s ease;
  transition: width .5s ease;
  width: 350px;
}

#Logo.small {
  width: 250px;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo_container"><img src="https://neilwhitedesign.co.uk/pt_testing_area/logo.png" class="largeLogo" id='Logo'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax_container">
  <div class="tagline" data-scroll-speed="3">This is the tagline</div>
  <div class="parallax" data-scroll-speed="2"><img src="https://neilwhitedesign.co.uk/pt_testing_area/landscape.jpg" /></div>
</div>

<div class="content" data-scroll-speed="100">Content Area</div>
<footer>&copy; 2021 &nbsp;|&nbsp; All rights reserved.</footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the revised script.

I've added it, and it works, but Dreamweaver says that line 29 contains a syntax error:

  const updateItems = () => {

Comment: That editor still exists? Try to enable ES6 features in your Dreamweaver, or use Babel and switch to a [better code editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/). Or if you want to stick to old ES5 - simply convert the [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to regular functions.  BTW, You're welcome @neilwhitedesign

Answer (score -1):

It is because you declare `window.onscroll` twice and therefor it overwrites the first declaration. You just have to add the call of `growShrinkLogo()` to the second `window.onscroll`.

**Working example:**

```js
var Logo = document.getElementById("Logo");
var endOfDocumentTop = 90;
var size = 0;

function growShrinkLogo() {
  var scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 90;

  if (size == 0 && scroll > endOfDocumentTop) {
    Logo.className = 'smallLogo';
    size = 1;
  } else if (size == 1 && scroll <= endOfDocumentTop) {
    Logo.className = 'largeLogo';
    size = 0;
  }
}

$.fn.moveIt = function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var instances = [];

  $(this).each(function() {
    instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
  });

  window.onscroll = function() {
    growShrinkLogo();
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    instances.forEach(function(inst) {
      inst.update(scrollTop);
    });
  }
}

var moveItItem = function(el) {
  this.el = $(el);
  this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};

moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop) {
  var pos = scrollTop / this.speed;
  this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + +pos + 'px)');
};

$(function() {
  $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

                  /* CSS Document */
                  /* 2. Clearfix*/
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1
}

                  /* 3. Images*/
a img {
  border: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

                  /* 4. Structure*/
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 1.9;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.parallax_container {
  width: 100%;
}

.parallax {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.tagline {
  color: white;
  font-size: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.2;
  z-index: 97;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  height: 900px;
  z-index: 98;
}

                  /* 5. Logo*/
.logo_container {
  width: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
}

#Logo {
  -webkit-transition: width .5s ease;
  -o-transition: width .5s ease;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}

.largeLogo {
  width: 350px;
}

.smallLogo {
  width: 250px;
}

                  /* 6. Footer */
footer {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">
  <div class="logo_container">
    <img src="https://neilwhitedesign.co.uk/pt_testing_area/logo.png" class="largeLogo" id='Logo'>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parallax_container">
  <div class="tagline" data-scroll-speed="3">
    This is the tagline
  </div>
  <div class="parallax" data-scroll-speed="2">
    <img src="https://neilwhitedesign.co.uk/pt_testing_area/landscape.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content" data-scroll-speed="100">
  Content Area
</div>
<footer>
  &copy; 2021&nbsp;|&nbsp; All rights reserved.
</footer>
```

Comment: Thats a really bad idea and not at all the right solution. You should not pollute Plugins with totally irrelevant code.

Comment: @neilwhitedesign if that answers your question you should mark it as accepted...

Comment: @Roko can you explain further why this is a really bad idea? From the looks of it, it's a simple update to OP's script, and the end functionality seems to behave the same way as your solution.

Comment: I think I see now - basically OP made a jQuery plugin that does 1 thing, so including other functionality (which only similarity is that it's triggered on scroll) unnecessarily makes the plugin more complicated. Additionally, and I didn't realize this at first, OP is using the `.onscroll` attribute rather than event binding, which is why they were running into this "overloaded scroll handling" issue in the first place.